# Django - Import Models from an installed Package

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have all of my Django models in another package which I install using pip in a Django app.

```
models_package
|   - models.py
|   - setup.py
```

and in `models.py` i have

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
class User(AbstractUser):
     ....
```

in my Django app i have

```
my_django_app
|   ...
|   models.py
website
|   ...
|   settings.py
manage.py
```

in `my_django_app.model` i have

```
from models_package.models import *
```

and in the `website` i have added `my_django_app` as an app (add it to INSTALLED_APP) and in `website.settings.py` i have

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "my_django_app.User"
```

but when i run `python manage.py runserver` i get:

```
RuntimeError: Model class my_django_app.models.User doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.
```

The Thing is `User` which comes from `models_packages.models` and `models_packages` is not a Django app which I add to `INSTALLED_APP` in settings.py. it is only a package containing all shared Models that I need in multiple different Django apps.

Is there any way to use models in `models_package.models` without adding  it to INSTALLED_APP inside `website.settings.py`

Comment: What is the reason for not adding `models_package` to `INSTALLED_APPS`? Trying to copy all the models to a different app seems odd

Comment: user should only be able to access everything through `my_django_app`. I just don't want the user be involved with the library that won't be used inside `website` directly.

Comment: You need to put the `models_package` app in `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to transform your 'my_django_app' to a django app:

all you need to do is to add **app.py** inside my_django_app package

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class ApiConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'my_django_app'
```

then you can add it to your INSTALLED_APP

Comment: I named the package `my_django_app` so that everyone understands that is it an actual app. So it already has `app.py`

Comment: well in that case you need to add it to your INSTALLED_APP, you have no other solution i think :(